# CSS: Why defining very long % values?

Tags: css

I have seen a few design where the developers have defined very long values in percentage. I am wondering what's the reason to write so long values, why not just round about? and how do you even calculate/convert such values?

For example (taken from a css file):

```
.thumbnail { width: 68.08510638297872%; }
table { font-size: 0.9166666666666667em; }
```

Comment: Maybe this CSS is generated automatically?

Comment: Those are created by IDEs,To my knowledge Such values are created when you re-size by dragging.

Comment: changing  width: 68.08510638297872% to width: 68.08510638297873% could break the internetz ;)

Comment: @Luca exactly, thats what I was scared of, and couldn't sleep whole night, and decided to ask the pros here :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks to me like those figures are generated programatically, not by humans directly. No Scotsman would do such a thing. Well, no *true* Scotsman :-)

Probably they come from a WYSIWYG layout editor that couldn't care less about readability, never expecting anyone to go and hand-edit the output.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely they are using some kind of CSS templating engine like [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/download.html) to generate stylesheets from code, and setting widths based percentage calculations.

Answer (score 3):

In the book `Responsive Web Design` Ethan Marcotte actually advocates leaving all the numbers after the decimal place when calculating percentage-based widths, to give the greatest accuracy, even when the developer is calculating the widths themselves using a calculator.

EDIT: I just dug out my copy of the book, and here is Marcotte's reasoning:

> Now, you might be tempted to round 0.45833333333333em to the nearest
>   sane-looking number—say, to 0.46em. But don’t touch that delete key!
>   It might make your eyes bleed to look ￼￼at it, but 0.458333333333333
>   perfectly represents our desired font size in proportional terms.
>   What’s more, browsers are perfectly adept at rounding off those excess
>   decimal places as they internally convert the values to pixels. So
>   giving them more information, not less, will net you a better result
>   in the end.

Comment: Still, *16* decimal digits of precision is excessive for CSS layout.

Comment: For sure. In RWD Ethan Marcotte's examples only have 14 decimal digits ;)

Comment: There's not going to any difference between 14 and, let's say, 5 decimal digits. I agree that rounding down to 2 decimal digits is not a good idea.

Comment: Hehe - yeah I think it's probably overkill too. In practice I have found that browsers differ in the way they do subpixel rounding, and when dealing with floated elements with percentage based widths it is sometimes necessary to round the widths down slightly, otherwise their combined width will be wider than their containing element.

Answer (score 2):

The most clients want a pixel perfect website inside the browser with scalabel font-size and web-content.
The developer has used the long percent, to get it perfect matched to the layouts.

Percent and em is an scalable unit not an pixel related unit and on some resolutions or font-size scales, the element do not match with the layouts and you can make it precise with more decimal places.

Newer Browser like Chrome or Firefox scale the font and the elements at once and this problem will not happen, but older browsers like ie 6-7 hasn't this feature and must learn it with em or percent units.

I hope it will help you to understand this problem